# Dropping multiple columns in pandas at once

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set consisting of 135 columns. I am trying to drop the columns which have empty data of more than 60%. There are some 40 columns approx in it. So, I wrote a function to drop this empty columns. But I am getting "Not contained in axis" error. Could some one help me solving this?. Or any other way to drop this 40 columns at once?

**My function:**

```
list_drop = df.isnull().sum()/(len(df))
def empty(df):
    if list_drop > 0.5:
        df.drop(list_drop,axis=1,inplace=True)
        return df
```

**Other method i tried:**

```
df.drop(df.count()/len(df)<0.5,axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome on Stackoverflow.
Could you please use the code tags to format your post?
That will make it easier for other people here to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `isnull` + `sum` and then use the mask to filter `df.columns`.

```
m = df.isnull().sum(0) / len(df) < 0.6
df = df[df.columns[m]]
```

---

**Demo**

```
df

       A      B     C
0   29.0    NaN  26.6
1    NaN    NaN  23.3
2   23.0   94.0  28.1
3   35.0  168.0  43.1
4    NaN    NaN  25.6
5   32.0   88.0  31.0
6    NaN    NaN  35.3
7   45.0  543.0  30.5
8    NaN    NaN   NaN
9    NaN    NaN  37.6
10   NaN    NaN  38.0
11   NaN    NaN  27.1
12  23.0  846.0  30.1
13  19.0  175.0  25.8
14   NaN    NaN  30.0
15  47.0  230.0  45.8
16   NaN    NaN  29.6
17  38.0   83.0  43.3
18  30.0   96.0  34.6

m = df.isnull().sum(0) / len(df) < 0.3   # 0.3 as an example

m

A    False
B    False
C     True
dtype: bool

df[df.columns[m]]

       C
0   26.6
1   23.3
2   28.1
3   43.1
4   25.6
5   31.0
6   35.3
7   30.5
8    NaN
9   37.6
10  38.0
11  27.1
12  30.1
13  25.8
14  30.0
15  45.8
16  29.6
17  43.3
18  34.6
```